# Using a URDF in Gazebo

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been following the URDF tutorials guide. However I got to the page on using URDF in Gazebo: http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20a%20URDF%20in%20Gazebo

Unfortunately this page seems to be missing the launch file referred to in Section 7. Putting it all Together.
ie Control.Launch

It would be nice if this launch file could be included somewhere as I don't see it in the urdf_tutorial package either.

I am not sure if this is the correct place to bring this up, so sorry if I should move this question elsewhere.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261327/using-a-urdf-in-gazebo/) by [biglotusturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/30307/biglotusturtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 165 on 2017-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The file does seem present on the Github repository that hosts the sources: [ros/urdf_tutorial](https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial/tree/7e93d633ca739bc4e59c708b8c4fecf007851395/launch).

Best place to report this - if you're sure there is something wrong - would be the [issue tracker](https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial/issues).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0